# What kind of expectations can I have for summer place rental in California and how can I save as much as possible?

Tags: california, rent, short-term

I'm going to intern in Bay Are this summer, in Mountain View. As far as I can tell, everyone is talking about renting an apartment on airbnb.com, but most of my peers expect way cheaper prices than those I could find there.

What kind of prices could I expect if I was lucky/knowledgeable and knew how to find a good place for three months? I'm willing to live with a few roommates as long as we have separate bedrooms.

Also, where would it be recommend to search? Any tips? For now, it's either airbnb or trying to find a sublease like crazy through all the spam on craigslist.

Comment: From my experience, you just aren't going to find cheap summer rentals in the Bay Area.  Your best bet is to try e.g. Craigslist for room rentals.

Answer (score 2):

If the company hosting the internship is hiring multiple interns, you could ask the company to put you in touch with each other to find a place together.

Your school or department might also have a facebook group / email list / bulletin board for this purpose.

Comment: We've already done that, but I'm just trying to see if there's anything I'm doing wrong.